# The test for divergence shows this harmonic series is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\frac 13 + \frac16 + \frac 19 + \frac {1}{12}+\frac{1}{15}+...$$

Is of the form $ \frac {1}{3}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (\frac{1}{n}) $ which makes it a p-series and also the harmonic series in particular, so the series is divergent.

But my classmate noticed that if we try to use the test for divergence:

when: $    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n \not= 0 $ the series is divergent

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {1}{3n}=0$$

The series should be convergent?

Edit: I initially put in the integral test instead of the divergence test by mistake

Comment: $\frac{1}{3x}$ is still non-integrable over $[1,+\infty)$.

Comment: But the integral in your expression diverges. Even if you correct the lower limit, and integrate from 1 to t, letting t go to infinity, you end up with log(t), which doesn't go to 0.

Comment: The claimed application of the integral test is incorrect.

Comment: I put in the wrong test form by mistake and I updated the question.

Comment: If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, you deduce nothing.

Comment: The test for divergence says: if $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\lim a_n = 0$. You've made the common mistake of thinking that the converse of this implication (if $\lim a_n=0$ then $\sum a_n$ converges) is also true, but it's not. The test for divergence is a one-way test. It's called test for divergence (not test for convergence) for a reason!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what the divergence test tells you. Is says that **if** $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq0$, **then** $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges. This is **not** the same as it's converse, i.e. that if the limit is zero then the series converges. There are lots of series where the terms go to zero but which do not converge, and the harmonic series is a prime example of this. The divergence test is simply there to help you rule out series from converging. Take for example the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1+n}{n}.$$

Since

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+n}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)=1,$$

the divergence test tells us that it diverges. However if we take the harmonic series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n},$$

we have that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0,$$

but the series still diverges (which can be checked using, for example, the integral test). What we can conclude is thus that

- If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges.
- If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ could either converge or diverge, but we cannot conclude anything.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the wrong interpretation of a *conditional statement*. For a given conditional statement $p\implies q$ (**i.e. if $p$ happens then $q$ happens too**), the only deduction you should draw is $\sim q\implies\sim p$ (**i.e.if $q$ doesn't happen then $p$ doesn't happen too**). In your case for the conditional $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n\ne 0\implies \sum a_n $ diverges, the **only** alternate condition you can conclude is $\sum a_n$ converges$\implies\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=0.$

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly: You're misusing the proof of the trivial-criteria, which states if $S_N$ is convergent then the belonging sequence $a_n$ converges $0$. But you used that if $a_n$ converges to $0$ then the series converges which is wrong. You cannot deduce anything if the sequence $a_n$ converges to $0$.

But the negation obviously holds, if the sequence does not converge to $0$ then the series does not converge, as you already said